# Does the openapi springboot server generator have a broken threading model?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, openapi-generator

So we're trying to use the OpenAPI generator and so far we've had mixed results.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download openapi generator jar: `wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openapitools/openapi-generator/4.0.3/openapi-generator-4.0.3.jar`
2. Generate springboot server for the petstore example: `java -jar openapi-generator-cli-4.0.3.jar generate -g spring   -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/examples/v3.0/petstore.yaml`

You'll end up with controller classes that look like this:

```
package org.openapitools.api;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import java.util.Optional;
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2019-08-06T15:08:49.070+01:00[Europe/London]")

@Controller
@RequestMapping("${openapi.swaggerPetstore.base-path:/v1}")
public class PetsApiController implements PetsApi {

    private final NativeWebRequest request;

    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    public PetsApiController(NativeWebRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(request);
    }

}
```

```
/**
 * NOTE: This class is auto generated by OpenAPI Generator (https://openapi-generator.tech) (4.0.3).
 * https://openapi-generator.tech
 * Do not edit the class manually.
 */
package org.openapitools.api;

import org.openapitools.model.Error;
import org.openapitools.model.Pet;
import io.swagger.annotations.*;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2019-08-06T15:08:49.070+01:00[Europe/London]")

@Validated
@Api(value = "pets", description = "the pets API")
public interface PetsApi {

    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Create a pet", nickname = "createPets", notes = "", tags={ "pets", })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Null response"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "unexpected error", response = Error.class) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/pets",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
    default ResponseEntity<Void> createPets() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }


    @ApiOperation(value = "List all pets", nickname = "listPets", notes = "", response = Pet.class, responseContainer = "List", tags={ "pets", })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "A paged array of pets", response = Pet.class, responseContainer = "List"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "unexpected error", response = Error.class) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/pets",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    default ResponseEntity<List<Pet>> listPets(@ApiParam(value = "How many items to return at one time (max 100)") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "limit", required = false) Integer limit) {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            for (MediaType mediaType: MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", "null");
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }


    @ApiOperation(value = "Info for a specific pet", nickname = "showPetById", notes = "", response = Pet.class, tags={ "pets", })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Expected response to a valid request", response = Pet.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "unexpected error", response = Error.class) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/pets/{petId}",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    default ResponseEntity<Pet> showPetById(@ApiParam(value = "The id of the pet to retrieve",required=true) @PathVariable("petId") String petId) {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            for (MediaType mediaType: MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", "null");
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }

}
```

So my question is this: everything I can find implies that Spring Controllers are multi-threaded and may handle multiple requests at once. Is the code generator broken? Am I interpreting this completely wrong?

The constructor for `PetsApiController` gives me pause. If it's being autowired once per request then that implies that there's only one per request?

```
    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    public PetsApiController(NativeWebRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The swagger code generators are notoriously bad, friend of mine said that the generators have the breadth but not the depth. You can generate skeletons for all sorts of languages and frameworks, but they have severe limitations. For example, try generating a good skeleton from a SwaggerDoc with `Page<Something>` or other Generics. I would very sadly say that they have almost no utility, and the tools tend to only work reliably the other way around, that is coding first and then generating the SwaggerDoc.

A place I worked at had a great concept I really liked whereby you would design your API first before implementing it, which sounds like you are trying to do. Some IDEs even support generated code, and there are plugins for build tools such as maven gradle etc to generate the code from your yaml.

But in practice I spent days trying to get desirable results from these tools and gave up. I think the real problem is Swagger/OpenAPI is still heavily viewed as documentation tool, not a design tool. I also think that trying to create an all encompassing project generator was setup to fail from the get-go.

I myself tried to customize the moustache templates which the generator used, but generics in Java were a nightmare, and you couldn't get the proper workflow working whereby I would change the SwaggerDoc and then update my code, as my approach was to generate an interface, and then implement that interface, but Annotations weren't inherited so I had to duplicate all the code anway meaning there was no benefit.

Comment: I have to say that's largely my experience too. I'm trying to beef up our API documentation practices (to whit: we should have some) but I've got to admit I'm kinda struggling. Any input or references would be useful.

Comment: Don't use any of the generators to create your project. Take a template out on the web which has SpringBoot and SpringFox configured. You can also use `swagger-diff` to compare swagger files and ensure that you are not making breaking changes to your API.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about springfox but I've been put off by a case we had in the past which is only really supported by OpenAPI3: we needed to pass an array of objects repenting domain operations which need to be done within the same transaction. Like a batch of multiple types of remote procedure calls, or you could compare it to a SQL transaction if you really stretch it. That needs the oneOf operator. I'm thinking that the only way around this is to manually create OpenAPI3 contacts, or maybe a different protocol altogether. Any thoughts?